# Access SQL Query Responding Very Slow

Tags: database, ms-access-2007

I am using MS ACCESS 2007 with C# and I am trying to execute following query..

My Table has three columns `Word`, `POS`, and `Freq` and has unique Records. Total record count is "millions of records".

This query works fine for me and return all correct results that I want:

```
Select Word, POS, Freq from TName Where Word **IN** ( SELECT Word  from TName                        Group By Word Having Count(*) > 1 ) Order By Word;
```

But when I tried the following similar query (in an EXE), then the system stops responding.

```
Select Word, POS, Freq from TName Where Word **NOT IN** ( SELECT Word  from TName                        Group By Word Having Count(*) > 1 ) Order By Word;
```

I also tried the second sql command in the *MS Access Query panel* and MS Access stop responding but return results very very slowly.

Please help me out...

Answer (score 0):

Since you're in Access, you can just make the SELECT IN its own query, and then just use an ordinary JOIN.

Query `WordCounts`:

```
SELECT Word from TName Group By Word Having Count(*) > 1
```

Your final query:

```
SELECT Word, POS, Freq from TName
INNER JOIN WordCounts ON TName.Word = WordCounts.Word
```

Answer (score 0):

Create the nested query as say QryWordsThatAppearMoreThanOnce
    SELECT Word from TName Group By Word Having Count(*) > 1

Then join

```
Select n.Word, n.POS, n.Freq from TName n
inner join QryWordsThatAppearMoreThanOnce q On q.Word = n.Word
Order By n.Word
```

The other would be

```
Select n.Word, n.POS, n.Freq from TName n
Left join QryWordsThatAppearMoreThanOnce q On q.Word = n.Word
and q.Word is null
Order By n.Word
```

Something like that anyway, possibility of some access weirdness coming into play.